# How to use an enumerator

Tags: ruby, enumeration, enumerator

In the Ruby Array Class documentation, I often find:

> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

Why would I not pass a block to `#map`? What would be the use of my doing just:

```
[1,2,3,4].map
```

instead of doing:

```
[1,2,3,4].map{ |e| e * 10 } # => [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Can someone show me a very practical example of using this enumerator?

Comment: "so well thought out!" – I *really* like Ruby, it is my favorite language, but *that* is not an attribute I would ever ascribe to Ruby :-D

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I'm so happy you dropped by. I really like your answers on this forum. I even told my *wife* about "this guy from Germany". Have you written any books?

Comment: @mjnissim Yes *Jörg* is really one of my [favorite answerer too..](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit_) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main distinction between an `Enumerator` and most<sup>†</sup> other data structures in the Ruby core library (`Array`, `Hash`) and standard library (`Set`, `SortedSet`) is that an `Enumerator` can be *infinite*. You cannot have an `Array` of all even numbers or a stream of zeroes or all prime numbers, but you can definitely have such an `Enumerator`:

```
evens = Enumerator.new do |y|
  i = -2
  y << i += 2 while true
end

evens.take(10)
# => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

zeroes = [0].cycle

zeroes.take(10)
# => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So, what can you do with such an `Enumerator`? Well, three things, basically.

1. `Enumerator` mixes in `Enumerable`. Therefore, you can use all `Enumerable` methods such as `map`, `inject`, `all?`, `any?`, `none?`, `select`, `reject` and so forth. Just be aware that an `Enumerator` may be infinite whereas `map` returns an `Array`, so trying to `map` an infinite `Enumerator` may create an infinitely large `Array` and take an infinite amount of time.
2. There are wrapping methods which somehow "enrich" an `Enumerator` and return a new `Enumerator`. For example, `Enumerator#with_index` adds a "loop counter" to the block and `Enumerator#with_object` adds a memo object.
3. You can use an `Enumerator` just like you would use it in other languages for external iteration by using the `Enumerator#next` method which will give you either the next value (and move the `Enumerator` forward) or `raise` a `StopIteration` exception if the `Enumerator` is finite and you have reached the end.

<sup>†</sup> Eg., an infinite range: `(1..1.0/0)`

Comment: Jörg, please consider writing a book. I'm sure there are subjects that are not properly covered yet. Like David Black and Russ Olsen, you have a gift for explaining which, when combined with a deep understanding of the material, can be very helpful to others.

Answer (score 9):

Good question.

What if we want to do multiple things with the enumerator that is created?  We don't want to process it now, because it means we may need to create another later?

```
my_enum = %w[now is the time for all good elves to get to work].map # => #<Enumerator: ["now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "elves", "to", "get", "to", "work"]:map>

my_enum.each(&:upcase) # => ["NOW", "IS", "THE", "TIME", "FOR", "ALL", "GOOD", "ELVES", "TO", "GET", "TO", "WORK"]
my_enum.each(&:capitalize) # => ["Now", "Is", "The", "Time", "For", "All", "Good", "Elves", "To", "Get", "To", "Work"]
```

Comment: vgoff, very good answer. But you said "We don't want to process it now, because it means we may need to create another later". I don't understand why it's not processed now, and why not just use an array.

Comment: If we simply use the enumerable right at that point, then I would have to repeat my .map command.  This way I do the map command once, and I can use the Enumerator more than just that one time.  This is the benefit of being able to get an Enumerator back.  We can use that one Enumerator instance over and over again.  We don't have to duplicate that work.

Comment: So is it more efficient as far as the machine is concerned? Does Ruby work less when I iterate over an enumerator twice rather than an array twice? or do I work less? or both?

Comment: If you create something once, it is done.  If you create the same thing more than once, then it is that many times the work.

Answer (score 4):

The feature of returning a `enumerable` when no block is given is mostly used when chaining functions from the enumerable class together. Like this:

```
abc = %w[a b c]
p abc.map.with_index{|item, index| [item, index]} #=> [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2]]
```

edit:

I think my own understanding of this behavior is a bit too limited in order to give a proper understanding of the inner workings of Ruby. I think the most important thing to note is that arguments are passed on in the same way they are for Procs. Thus if an array is passed in, it will be automatically 'splatted' (any better word for this?). I think the best way to get an understanding is to just use some simple functions returning enumerables and start experimenting.

```
abc = %w[a b c d]
p abc.each_slice(2)                #<Enumerator: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:each_slice(2)>
p abc.each_slice(2).to_a           #=> [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
p abc.each_slice(2).map{|x| x}     #=> [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
p abc.each_slice(2).map{|x,y| x+y} #=> ["ab", "cd"]
p abc.each_slice(2).map{|x,| x}    #=> ["a", "c"] # rest of arguments discarded because of comma.
p abc.each_slice(2).map.with_index{|array, index| [array, index]} #=> [[["a", "b"], 0], [["c", "d"], 1]]
p abc.each_slice(2).map.with_index{|(x,y), index| [x,y, index]}   #=> [["a", "b", 0], ["c", "d", 1]]
```

Comment: Hirolau, this is a very interesting answer. I find the level of abstraction a little difficult to get my mind around at this point. I'll be happy if you explain a little more but even if you don't, at least I've learned that you can chain methods this way and I'll try and chew on it some time.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to hirolau's answer, there is another method `lazy` that you can combine to modify the enumerator.

```
a_very_long_array.map.lazy
```

If `map` always took a block, then there would have to be another method like `map_lazy`, and similarly for other iterators to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html) A class which allows both internal and external iteration

```
=> array = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> array.map
=> #<Enumerator: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]:map>
=> array.map.next
=> 2
=> array.map.next_values
=> [0] 2
```

Comment: Decent example, but then you also need to know that you are waiting for an exception to happen if you exceed the bounds of the enumerator.

Comment: it just a simple example, i dont use this technic

Comment: Thanks Monk_Code, but I figured out you'd probably want me to do `map = array.map` and then use `map.next`, right?

Comment: in this example enumerator(array.map) its like freezy iterator you can pass each step without block.

Answer (score 0):

I guess sometimes you want to pass the `Enumerator` to another method, despite where this `Enumerator` came from: `map`, `slice`, whatever:

```
def report enum
  if Enumerator === enum
    enum.each { |e| puts "Element: #{e}" }
  else
    raise "report method requires enumerator as parameter"
  end
end

> report %w[one two three].map
# Element: one
# Element: two
# Element: three

> report (1..10).each_slice(2)    
# Element: [1, 2]
# Element: [3, 4]
# Element: [5, 6]
# Element: [7, 8]
# Element: [9, 10]
```

Comment: Thank bro. But again, *why* an Enumerator and not just an Array?

Comment: Just because you might implement your own `Enumerator`. And because there are `Kernel#to_enum` and `Kernel#enum_for` helpers. `Enumerator` is more general, than `Array`: take a look at examples [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-new).